# Netsuite SSv2 How to Update Filters of a Saved Search

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I am trying to figure out how to update the filters of a group saved searches.

I save the filters from a generic saved search:

```
var searchGen = search.load({

            id: 'customsearch_ca_export_detail_search__38'

        });

        var filter = searchGen.filters;
```

Then I plug the filters into the searches using a loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i<selectedMarkets.length; i++){

                var selectedSearchId = marketplaces[selectedMarkets[i]].searchId;

                var searchObj = search.load({id:selectedSearchId});

                var filters = searchObj.filters;

                filters = filter;

                searchObj.save();

            }
```

All my variables contain the right information. But pushing the data from the generic saved search to the searches I want to update is not working:

```
filters = filter;
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I spent a couple weeks going back and forth with NetSuite reps, and they have confirmed that there is a bug with `search.save()` that is preventing this from working.

They have filed a defect for now. Just FYI for anyone else interested.

Answer (score 2):

Try deconstructing the filters and reconstructing them as such:

```
for (var i in selectedMarkets){
    var selectedSearchId = marketplaces[selectedMarkets[i]].searchId;
    var searchObj = SEARCHMODULE.load({id:selectedSearchId});
    var oldFilters = searchObj.filters;
    var newFilters = [];

    for (var k in oldFilters) {
        var oldFilter = oldFilters[k];
        var filter = {};
        filter.name = oldFilter.name;
        filter.operator = oldFilter.operator;
        filter.values = oldFilter.values;
        filter.join = oldFilter.join;

        if (typeof(oldFilter.formula) !== 'undefined'){
            filter.formula = oldFilter.formula;
        }

        newFilters.push(SEARCHMODULE.createFilter(filter));
    }

    searchObj.filters = newFilters;
    searchObj.save();
}
```

Note: You need to adjust the code to work for summary filters.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Super close, try:</strike>

```
searchObj.filters = filter;

searchObj.save();
```

As written, you're just setting the 'local' variable `filters` to filter, not the actual search object parameter.

This is a pretty terrible answer and **extreme** caution is recommended, but might work for your purposes if you really need to do this in SS2.  You *could* recreate the whole search, **delete the original**, and save the recreated search:

```
    var searchObj = search.load({
    id: 'customsearch_test'
});
log.debug('first search', searchObj.filterExpression);

var otherSearch = search.load({
    id: 'customsearch_test_2'
});
log.debug('second search', otherSearch.filterExpression);

var newSearch = search.create({
    type: otherSearch.searchType,
    filters: searchObj.filters, //everything is unchanged but the filters
    columns: otherSearch.columns,
    title: otherSearch.title || "testy test", //apparently the title doesn't come through in search.load()?!?
    id: otherSearch.id,
    isPublic: otherSearch.isPublic
});

search.delete({
    id: 'customsearch_test_2'
});

var id = newSearch.save();

log.debug('result', id);
var otherSearchAgain = search.load({
    id: 'customsearch_test_2'
});
log.debug('second search, after save', otherSearchAgain.filterExpression);
```

Comment: I just tried that, and it still doesn't seem to update the searches. I plugged in log.debug lines to see what "filter" and "searchObj.filters" render, and they both show they correct content. But for some reason the searches are still not updating.

searchObj.filters = filter;
                    
log.debug('Generic Filters in Loop',filter);
                    
log.debug('Updated Filters',searchObj.filters);
                    
searchObj.save();

Comment: I see that now.  Totally crazy.  I posted a possible solution, but it's not complete and is pretty high risk, relatively speaking.

Comment: Crazy. I'm guessing that would work but I will need to think through the implications for sure. Thanks for taking the time to help me out.